# Получить источник трансляции вк

Tags: url, трансляция

Подскажите пожалуйста возможно ли найти ссылку на трансляцию в Ютубе, которая встроена в ВКонтакте (я знаю, что они устраивают из Ютуба, но не могу найти канал)? Есть либо на в коде страницы?